# my app using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an existing app in the store and uses "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" to access the storage. This code has worked from 2.3 to Lollipop (on my Galaxy S5, Verizon) allowing users to read/write into a directory called Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/MyFooBar. Recently my S5 was updated to 6.0 Marshmallow and now my S5 (and customers too) are getting the error that /storage/emulated/0/MyFooBar cannot be created.

Per android API calls to Environment.getExternalStorageState() and comparing to Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED states it is mounted and Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is no.

All these calls have been the same and now w/ S5 and Marshmallow are broken.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,Jim

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a dangerous permission and it is not granted automatically, so you should implement the new permissions scheme to get it working on Android Marshmallow.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html